# What does byte[rax] represent in x86 assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86

If it represents the 8 least significant bits of rax, how is it different from al. 
If I do
`add byte[rax] 1` and an overflow happens, does it overflow into the carry flag or ah

Edit: changed `add byte[rdi] 1` to `add byte[rax] 1`

Comment: That takes the byte at the address pointed to by RDI and add adds 1 to it. PS:Your  instruction and the title of the question don't match In one palce you say RAXand the other RDI.

Comment: It references the byte pointed to by the register `RAX` as address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Microsoft assemblers, the syntax is

```
        add     byte ptr [rax],1
```

Either the pointer or immediate value need to state a size type (byte, word, dword, qword), in order for the assembler to determine the size of the memory location being modified. For most X86 assemblers, the type is stated with the pointer, but there may be assemblers where the type is stated with the immediate value. Microsoft assemblers use the pointer to determine the type. If the pointer was to a structure member, such as

```
        add     [rax].mystruct.struct_member,1
```

then the type would be implied by the size of the structure member.

The destination is a memory location, so AH is not affected. The carry, overflow, and zero flags will be updated.

Comment: Why do you mention MASM?  The OP appears to be using NASM syntax, (but without commas?) where `byte` is an operand-size specifier.  NASM doesn't have any magical mechanism for memory operands to imply an operand size; there has to be something explicit in the instruction (a register or a keyword).

Comment: @PeterCordes - I wasn't sure if the OP was using NASM or if he was using MASM and left out `ptr` by mistake. This is why I answered that `either the pointer or the immediate value need to state a type`, depending on the assembler. I updated my answer to reflect this, but it appears the OP already understood my answer. I don't know if any X86 assemblers allow a type on the immediate value instead of the pointer, but I mentioned both cases in case there are such assemblers.